# Linux MD RAID with btrfs stuck and consume 100 % CPU

Tags: linux, hardware, mdadm, btrfs

#### The issue

During last several weeks, I am experiencing annoying issue on my physical server with Linux software RAID 6 (md, mdadm) with btrfs file system on it.

Once in several days (irregularly, as I noticed), the `md1_raid6` process starts to consume *100 % of one CPU core* and during that time, all file system access on btrfs on top of this raid device get stucked (user space processes hangs in *disk sleep* state).

In most cases, after several "IO" actions like listing files (`ls`), accessing btrfs information (`btrfs filesystem`, `btrfs subvolume`), or accessing the device (`dd` and so), the file system gets *magically unstucked* and `md1_raid6` process released from its "live lock" (or whatever it is cycled in).

The worse case happens sometimes, when I am not successful with this "magic unstucking". Then I am not able to even *kill* the processes stucked in *disk sleep* state and I am forced to reset the system.

When my issue happens, I found very often similar messages in kernel `dmesg` log:

```
INFO: task md1_reclaim:910 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
```

with included call trace.

However, there are some more "blocked" tasks, like `btrfs` and `btrfs-transaction` with call trace also included.

#### Questions

1. What should be the cause of this problem?
2. What should I do to mitigate this issue?
3. Could it be a hardware problem? How can I track this?

#### What I have done so far

- I keep the system up-to-date, with latest stable kernel provided by Debian packages
- I run both `btrfs scrub` and `fsck.btrfs` to exclude btrfs file system issue.
- I have read all the physical disks (with `dd` command) and perform SMART self tests to exclude disks issue (though read/write `badblocks` were not checked yet).
- I have also moved all the files out of affected file system, create *a new btrfs file system* (with recent `btrfs-progs`) and moved files back. This issue yet appeared again.
- I have tried to attach `strace` to cycled `md1` process, but unsuccessfully (is it even possible to `strace` running kernel thread?)
- Of course, I have tried to find similar issues around the web, but I was not successful.

#### Some detailed facts

OS information

- Debian 10 buster (stable release)
- Linux kernel 5.5 (from Debian backports)

Hardware information

- 8 core/16 threads amd64 processor (AMD EPYC 7251)
- 6 SATA HDD disks (Seagate Enterprise Capacity)
- 2 SSD disks (Intel D3-S4610)

RAID information

- All Linux MD RAID (no HW RAID used)
- RAID1 over 2 SSD (`md0`)

  - On top of this RAID1 is a LVM with logical volumes for:

    - root file system
    - swap
    - *RAID6 write journal*
- RAID6 over 6 HDD and 1 LV as write journal (`md1`)

  - This is the affected device

Usage information

- Affected RAID6 block device is directly formatted to btrfs
- This file system is used to store backups
- Backups are performed via `rsnapshot`
- `rsnapshot` is configured to use *btrfs snapshots* for hourly and daily backups and `rsync` to copy new backups

Other IO operations

- There is ongoing monitoring through *Icinga* which uses `iostat` internally to monitor I/O
- SMART selftests run periodically (on weekly and monthly basis)

Comment: I guess if the kernel reports a blocked kernel thread then there is a bug in any case. I suggest you report your case to the MD mailing list.

Comment: Ok, thanks @HaukeLaging. I am not sure whether it is MD or BTRFS issue at the moment. Also, I want to eliminate my misuse of these technologies first.

Comment: Have you ever heard of `cat /proc/mdstat`? Examining syslog around the event may be also helpful.